# How to do an onmouseover text binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How can I bind text to element when mouse overs it?

Javascript I have so far:

```
self.books = ko.observable();
self.leftBooks = self.books() - self.allBooks();
```

Corresponding view:

```html
<button data-bind="text: books"></button>
```

When the mouse hovers over the button I want to show `leftBooks` variable. When the mouse hover leaves I want to show the `books` variable.

Comment: Please have a look at [the relevant documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) and give it a go. If you run into any specific problems show the code with the issue and explain why/where you got stuck. Good luck!

Comment: @Jeroen I stuck at this point. I can't figure out how to change binding text. I searched stackoverflow but did not find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ukv59/5/

What I did:

- create a computed observable for your 'leftBooks'
- create a computed observable for the button caption
- added some fields so you can test that it actually works

Code:

```
self.allBooks = ko.observable(50);
self.books = ko.observable(10);
self.leftBooks = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.allBooks() - self.books();
});
self.showLeftBooks = ko.observable(false);
self.buttonText = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.showLeftBooks() ? self.leftBooks() : self.books();
});
self.mouseOver = function () {
    self.showLeftBooks(true);
}
self.mouseOut = function () {
    self.showLeftBooks(false);
}
```

Edit: Alexander's update to his answer does pretty much the same thing, but with one property less. In my opinion it's a matter of taste whether you want the extra opbservable 'showLeftBooks' to be introduced. I feel it makes the intention of the code a little more clear, but you can omit it completely if you like.

Comment: How can I access `button` element if I want want to disable button when mouse hovers over?

Comment: You want to look into the enable-binding. why would you ONLY disable a button on hover though?

Answer (score 1):

Use `event` binding for this:

Html:

```
<button data-bind="text: booksTitle, event: {mouseover: mouseOver, mouseout: mouseOut}"></button>
```

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.books = ko.observable(10);
    self.allBooks = ko.observable(100);
    self.leftBooks = self.books() - self.allBooks();

    self.booksTitle = ko.observable(10);

    self.mouseOver = function () {
        self.booksTitle(self.leftBooks);
    }

    self.mouseOut = function () {
        self.booksTitle(self.books());
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/Ukv59/2/)

Comment: I already used `event` binding, but I don't want to change variable value, I just want to change `text` binding variable of element from `books` to `leftBooks`

Comment: how can I access `button` element if I want want to disable button when mouse hovers over?

Comment: You should `disable` binding for this case. Access dom elements from knockout viewModel is very bad practice.